# Authenticating a dash app within a flask app using firebase

Tags: authentication, flask, plotly-dash, werkzeug

I am using firebase authentication to authenticate my flask app. This works perfectly for all the flask views. However I can't manage for this to work with the dash view. I have attached below a very simple minimal example without firebase where I have one flask page `hello` and one `dashboard` page. I wrap the views with the decorator `check_token()` which currently should just redirect all views to the login page. This works for the flask views `/hello` and `/`, but not for the dash view `dashboard`.

Confusingly, the decorator isn't even being run for the dashboard view as evidenced by the print statements.

`routes.py`

```
from flask import current_app as app
def check_token(f):
    print("RUNNING check_token")
    def wrap(*args,**kwargs):
        print("RUNNING wrap")
        token = request.cookies.get("token")
        if not token:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__name__ = f.__name__
    return wrap

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/hello')
@check_token
def hello():
    return 'hello world!'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return "This is the login page"

@app.route('/dashboard')
@check_token
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/dash1')
```

`application.py`

```
from dash import Dash
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask, request,render_template, url_for, redirect


def init_dash(dash_app1):
    dash_app1.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app1 for dashboards')])
    return dash_app1

def init_app():
    server = Flask(__name__)
    dash_app1 = Dash(__name__, server = server, url_base_pathname='/dashboard/' )
    dash_app1 = init_dash(dash_app1)
    with server.app_context():
        import routes
    app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {
        '/dash1': dash_app1.server,
    })
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 8090, init_app(), use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I have been struggling for the last two days to try and get this work

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work with this code snippet that I found from an obscure github thread

```
from dash import Dash
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
import dash_html_components as html
from flask import Flask, request,render_template, url_for, redirect
from utils import check_token

def protect_views(app,bpn):
    for view_func in app.server.view_functions:
        print(view_func)
        if view_func.startswith(bpn):
            app.server.view_functions[view_func] = check_token(app.server.view_functions[view_func])
    
    return app

def init_dash(dash_app1):
    dash_app1.layout = html.Div([html.H1('Hi there, I am app1 for dashboards')])
    return dash_app1

def init_app():
    server = Flask(__name__)
    bpn = '/dashboard/'
    dash_app1 = Dash(__name__, server = server, url_base_pathname=bpn )
    dash_app1 = init_dash(dash_app1)
    dash_app1 = protect_views(dash_app1, bpn)
    with server.app_context():
        # dash_app1 = protect_views(dash_app1)

        import routes
    app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {
        '/dash1': dash_app1.server,
    })
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 8090, init_app(), use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```